# Theme options not displaying correctly after theme update

Tags: theme-development

I am redesigning a theme options panel but when I present to a client, the display is not exactly the same with the one I made. I investigate on this problem and it seems that he is actually seeing a part of the old version of the theme options panel so a full clearing of the browser cache should solve the problem. I have replicate his issue and clearing the browser solve this one.

But I'm looking for some ways to somehow reset or flush old changes on the browser for the theme options without actually clearing your cache. As I have observed the client is not yet ready to clear his browser probably due to some important reasons.

Is there a solution to this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers will cache any files so it's hard to know without more detail *which* files are your issue. That said, this happens most often with CSS and JS files, and WordPress is built to address this issue. [wp_enqueue_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) and [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) each have a parameter for file version (4th param in each). So long as you use these functions and up this version whenever you make a change, you should never run into caching issues with either file type.